# is there anyway to take you tube videos and get them on my ipod

Tags: ipod, youtube

i often see you tube video links but dont have time to view them at my pc.  is there any quick way to download these to my ipod

Comment: given that there's no Flash on the ipod/iphone devices, this *must* be done with a computer.  therefore it is definitely computer related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On of my favorite services for this is [**Vixy**](http://vixy.net/). Simply paste in the URL and in the **Conver To:** dropdown select **MP4 for iPod/PSP**. This file can then be placed directly onto your iPod.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube-ipod.net/

There you go!